# How to apply url in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a page (commerce.php), I want to give the link to the below-mentioned button, how I do that in Yii framework?  My page path is frontend/views/site/commerce.php.

Below code is belong from index.php page

```
<a href="/yii2-my-appmp/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fmarket"><button class="btn"><h5>Marketing Team</h5></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::a(
     'Marketing Team', ['site/market'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
); ?>
```